How to run Artillery on a Password protected Vercel URL
Unable to trigger artillery test in top vercel password protected url.
I would like to run a artillery test in top of the vercel deployed code url which is protected by a password.
This is my .yml
config:
  target: '<my url>'
  phases:
    - duration: 1 # Total duration of the test in seconds
      arrivalRate: 1 # Initial arrival rate of users per second
      rampTo: 1 # Ramp up to 1137 users over the duration
      name: 'Ramp-up Users'
  engines:
    playwright:
      config:
        extraHTTPHeaders:
          'x-vercel-protection-bypass' : "<my token>"
        baseURL: '<my url>'

      # Optional: Add Playwright-specific configurations here if needed.
  processor: './automation-test/loadtest/artillery/search.ts'
scenarios:
  - engine: playwright
    testFunction: 'artilleryScript'


and my search.ts
fileimport { Page, expect } from '@playwright/test';
async function testSearch(page: Page) {
   await page.goto('');
   await page.getByTestId('search-input-header').click();
   await page.getByTestId('search-input-header').fill('test');
   await page.getByTestId('search-input-header').press('Enter');
   await expect(page.getByTestId('clear-button')).toBeVisible();
}

export async function artilleryScript(page: Page) {
   await testSearch(page);
}

when i try to run artillery run load-test.yml
I see that my link is not open with token password so getting
locator.click: Timeout 30000ms exceeded.
Call log:

waiting for getByTestId('search-input-header')

how do i pass x-vercel-protection-bypass for my target url ?

I've answered this on the Github Discussions on Artillery Github repo too, but for reference, the issue here is you're using engines.playwright.config to set the extraHTTPHeaders option, but that's not the right place to set it in Artillery config. It should be under engines.playwright.contextOptions.
More information in the docs: https://www.artillery.io/docs/reference/engines/playwright#example-2-set-extra-http-headers

Thank you @bernardobridge !
Much appreciated.
Now test run only on headed mode, headless its failing. stuck on there :(
